# Quickest way of storing and accessing Strings in an array

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hash-function

I know I could go through a for loop like this (see code) and i could also add to the array in the same fashion but is there a quicker way. I don't want to use any other java API as i want to practice array's. Would using a hash function allow me to store my variables quicker and then find a certain word quicker?

edit: The problem is when using 10,000+ words the delay increases larger than 1ms

Thanks :)

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(array[i].equals(word)) 
        count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2 dimensional array :

Array [Alphabet] [Words starting with that alphabet]

Comment: This is a very simplified version of a hash map. The hash function of using the first letter is not a very good one, but if you can't use a hash map directly, it's not that bad.

Comment: Adding to a 2d array would increase the time because i would need two for loops right?

Comment: yes you are right, but the guy wanted to use and practice arrays only, so i replied with that answer :)

Comment: @MichaelMyers how could i create a simplified version of a hash map for this? Could you point me in the right direction please

Comment: @kingsta: no dude you just check the first alphabet of the word and directly access the array starting with those words

Comment: @Kingsta1993: A hash map first uses some function to calculate a hash value of each item, then stores the item in a "bucket" based on the hash value. That's what this answer suggests: the hash function is simply the first letter of the word, then the bucket is the array corresponding to that letter.

Comment: let me give you a better insight suppose your array is something like :
array[26][]

now whenever you encounter a word, fetch its first alphabets ascii value, if it is <=90 add 32 in it and then subtract 97, this will take care of both small and capital alphabets and access the array

was i clear?

Comment: Note that this works best if you disallow non-English letters. If one of your words, is, say, [Åland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85land_Islands), you'll have problems. Or you could just make a 27th bucket for such words.

Comment: @Michael: Yes there would be a lot of cases to consider if we start using non-English letters :)

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-sort the array and then use a binary-chop search on it. This would only be useful if you are looking for many words.

If you allow other structures then you can usually achieve `O(1)` lookup times.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your processing 10,000 words you can expect some delays. Depending on what word is set to you might be able to filter a bit better but as far as your code shows that's the best way to do it.